# Alternatives to alter table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

We use mysql(AWS aurora) to store data of our online payment transactions. One of our tables, in which each row stores information of a particular transaction, has more than 1 billion rows.

How can I go about adding a new attribute for a transaction ? Altering this table is not possible because of large amount of time required to do so.

Only possible solution seems to be creating a new table which stores key-value pairs for each transaction. Are there other more efficient ways to do this, assuming altering table structure is not possible ?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/182359/10827

Comment: @juergend "assuming altering table structure is not possible"

Comment: If you can't alter the table and need another column, then there is no other way than create a new table with the additional data.

Comment: MySQL supports online inplace ddl operations, so while it might take some time (and might slow your server down during that time), you can keep using the table, and I would not completely neglect that option. And if you are on MySQL 8 already, it even supports instantly adding a column (under some preconditions).

Comment: @Solarflare, Have you done an in-place ALTER to add a column to a table that has > 1 billion rows? It still takes a long, long time. Any changes you make in the meantime are queued up in a fixed-size buffer (128MB by default). If the buffer fills up, the ALTER fails. Then the buffer needs to be merged into the table, whether the ALTER failed or succeeded. The table is locked during this merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to create a parallel table.  It would have the same `PRIMARY KEY` as your current table (but without `AUTO_INCREMENT`).  And it would have the 'new' column(s).

Then you would `JOIN` on the PK to fetch both old and new columns at the same time.

Pros:  No downtime, no big ALTER, etc.

Cons:  Now the table is split in two.  Subsequent columns being added go through the same dilemma.

Alternative to the alternative:  Put a JSON column in that new table.

Pros:  Very open-ended wrt adding more columns.

Cons:  Can't index it very well.  (This depends on what version you are using.)

Answer (score 2):

At my work, we have quite a few tables with over 1 billion rows. Developers add or remove columns, change data types, add or remove indexes, etc. Any kind of ALTER TABLE.

The way we do this is to use [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html), a free tool available from Percona. It allows you to do long-running schema changes, and you can still read and write the table while it's doing the change in the background.

It still takes a long time to do a change to a large table. In the largest cases, it takes weeks. But it doesn't block your work in the meantime.